# command "dir \s \b" in Windows 10 cmd gives me "File Not Found" error

Tags: cmd.exe

It is very strange that this file exists, even I copy and paste its address in run and the file opens

> ```
> C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\ 
> C:\>dir \s \b > C:\Users\FNGeek\Desktop\filelist.txt
> File Not Found
>
> C:\>
> ```

Comment: Please post text information as text.

Comment: dir /s /b, forward slash for the switches.

Comment: When using a command in the wrong way, it will return you in error messages, there is nothing *strange* about that. See **[`dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**

Answer (score 1):

> C:>dir \s \b > C:\Users\FNGeek\Desktop\filelist.txt File Not Found

Due to using back-slash for command switches, these are interpreted as part of a file path. For switches use forward-slash instead.

So, `dir /s /b > C:\Users\FNGeek\Desktop\filelist.txt` [enter]

If you then still get 'file not found', double check the path for output file.